# Default font used by PSTricks?

Tags: fonts, inkscape, postscript

I am trying to recreate this drawing:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cartesian_coordinates_2D.svg

There are instructions at the end, but I want to skip some steps. Namely, I want to import the ps file directly into InkScape.

I was able to do this, but Inkscape switched to a sans serif font instead of the original serif font. OTOH, when I load the ps file into ghostscript the font is displayed like it should.

Why is it wrong in Inkscape, and how can I fix it? Also, what is PSTricks' default serif font?

Thanks.

Comment: It's Computer Modern, if can judge from the pdf I produced, which is  also converted to  a sans serif font. I also tried with MinionPro, which a font known to the system, and I had the same result. It's a problem with Inkscape (settings?)

Comment: I cannot find the font in my fonts folder. I do have MikTex and Ghostscript installed. Are there other locations I can check for it? (Windows 7)

Comment: Which font can't you find? Computer Modern? There's a whole bunch of fonts, in  `…\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\type1\public\amsfonts\`

Comment: Inkscape can't use those fonts until they are installed in the Windows  'fonts' directory. Which font files do I need to install?

Comment: The `.pfb`s and the `.pfm`s.

Comment: I installed the fonts, but Inkscape is still using the default sans serif instead of CM serif when importing ps, eps or pdf versions of the same document.

Comment: I'm not surprised: I tried with Minion Pro, which comes with Adobe Reader, and can be used by any ‘standard’  Windows application (e.g. Libre Office), and I had the same problem. I think it's a settings problem with Inkscape.